# FFC 13 pin cable extension

Tags: lcd, cables, ffc

I have this 13 pin FFC cable inside my Canon Typestar 5 thermal typewriter. It connects the LCD display to the main board. I'd like to pull the display outside the machine and for that I need an extension (not long).
[image]
Do extensions exist for such cable? If so where do I find one?

PS: There is a number of posts on extending FFC cables but they are all quite technical. I just need to find an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your situation the easiest way would simply be to use a 13 contacts to 13 contacts board, then a new 13 pin FFC cable.

[image]
[image]

Both can be bought from common suppliers. These two are specifically from amazon.

[13 pin adapter board](https://www.amazon.ca/uxcell%C2%AE-Extension-Connector-Aapter-Extend/dp/B07RT6YPNW/ref=sr_1_79?keywords=ffc%201mm%20pcb&qid=1581048310&sr=8-79)

[13 pin FFC 150mm cable](https://www.amazon.ca/uxcell%C2%AE-Flexible-Cable-Ribbon-Player/dp/B07RWPXQQB/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=ffc%2013&qid=1581048422&sr=8-3)

While I'm pretty sure your pitch is 1.0mm....measure it yourself to be sure.

Comment: That's very useful. Thanks. Those would have to come from China but Amazon US sell them too.

Comment: I gave a link to the canadian site. They ship from the US. If your location is in the US then amazon.com delivers it in less than a week at most locations. https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Extension-Connector-Aapter-Extend/dp/B07RT6YPNW/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=13+ffc&qid=1581049425&refresh=1&sr=8-5  https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Flexible-Cable-Ribbon-Player/dp/B07RWPXQQB/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=13+ffc&qid=1581049541&refresh=1&sr=8-7

Comment: Just be real sure of your pitch!

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The CA option takes much longer to ship.

Comment: I wish they'd give the cable width. Mine is 17mm. I guess that makes the pitch larger than 1mm, since there are 13 pins, but it's not so easy to tell.

Comment: Pitch is the distance between each pin on the cable. Measure between two metal bands on the connector, from the middle of each band. It can be 1mm, 1.25mm, 1.27mm, etc. If your pitch isn't the right one, the cable wont fit.

Comment: It's 1.25mm. But I can't find adapters for that pitch.

Comment: Hmm, then I'll post another suggestion: solder together two FFC connectors back to back. You can use a 14 pin FFC connector all the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104172/discussion-between-jeanb-and-natsu-kage).